# Incorrect Wordpress and Electronics icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, obsolete, icons, api-v1.1

[image]
Currently Meta Icon

[image]
Currently Main Icon

With all the other sites (except electronics, which has the same icon for both), Meta has the B&W or sepia icon, while the main site's icon is coloured.
This is also the case with the site's favicons.

With Electronics the icon is (same as the main site):
[image]
but it's favicon is(ie B&W):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get a similar but different problem: when polling [`http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites?page=2`](http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites?page=2), I get the regular icon for Electronics.SE and Electronics.SE Meta.

Both:

- http://sstatic.net/electronics/img/apple-touch-icon.png
- http://sstatic.net/electronicsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png

...are identical and probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant about Electronics, but it just didn't come across right :)

Answer (score 0):

This bug was written against a now decommissioned version of the API (Version 1.1) but was fixed long ago and never a problem in the current API version.

For example, [the API's `/sites` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=100&filter=!YOI0e0UGrO0D-eo5wgXw5igJUn&run=true) returns:

**Main         Meta**
[image] 
[image]

[image] 
[image]

That is:

- [cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpress/img/apple-touch-icon.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpress/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
- [cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpressmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpressmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
- [cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronics/img/apple-touch-icon.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronics/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
- [cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronicsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronicsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

Which is all correct. It matches the live site styling and the meta styles are grayed versions of the main site -- just as shown on the live metas.